# How to loop through innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to loop through `innerHTML` to get a different ID value in order to not get the error:

```
Can not read property of `null` or `0`.
```

My first part of code create a loop with a single ID for each select:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= cantidadVegana; i++){

    $('#light').append( `                         
    <p>Entrada: </p>
    <select id="EntradaLightID`+ i.toString() +`">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="EntradaLight 1">Entrada 1</option>
        <option value="EntradaLight 2">Entrada 2</option>
        <option value="EntradaLight 3">Entrada 3</option>
    </select>
    <p>Plato fuerte: </p>
    <select id="PlatoLightID`+ i.toString() +`">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="PlatoLight Fuerte 1">Plato Fuerte 1</option>
        <option value="PlatoLight Fuerte 2">Plato Fuerte 2</option>
        <option value="PlatoLight Fuerte 3">Plato Fuerte 3</option>
    </select>
    <p>Postre: </p>
    <select id="PostreLightID`+ i.toString() +`">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="PostreLight 1">Postre 1</option>
        <option value="PostreLight 2">Postre 2</option>
        <option value="PostreLight 3">Postre 3</option>
    </select>`
    )}
}
```

The second part of code tries to get the value of each of the element ID created in the previews code and stores it on a variable.

```
for(var i = 0; i<= cantidadVegana; i++){
    entradaLight=_('EntradaLightID'[i].toString()).value;
    platoFuerteLight = _('PlatoLightID'[i].toString()).value;
    PostreLight = _('PostreLightID'[i].toString()).value;
}
```

The last part of code sends the information store in to:

```
for(i=0; i<= cantidadVegana; i++){
    _("entradaLight")[i].toString().innerHTML = "Selecciono para la entrada light " + entradaLight[i].toString();
    _("platoFuerteLight")[i].toString().innerHTML = "Selecciono para el plato light " + platoFuerteLight[i].toString();
    _("postreLight")[i].toString().innerHTML = "Selecciono para el postre light " + PostreLight[i].toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you check the ids after rendering with help of web developer toolbar?  This looks strange to me: id="EntradaLightID`+ i.toString() +`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to concatinate the string like this

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= cantidadVegana; i++){
    $('#light').append(''+                         
'<p>Entrada: </p>'+
    '<select id="EntradaLightID'+ i.toString() +'">'+
        '<option value=""></option>'+
        '<option value="EntradaLight 1">Entrada 1</option>'+
        '<option value="EntradaLight 2">Entrada 2</option>'+
        '<option value="EntradaLight 3">Entrada 3</option>'+
    '</select>'+
    '<p>Plato fuerte: </p>'+
    '<select id="PlatoLightID'+ i.toString() +'">'+
        '<option value=""></option>'+
        '<option value="PlatoLight Fuerte 1">Plato Fuerte 1</option>'+
        '<option value="PlatoLight Fuerte 2">Plato Fuerte 2</option>'+
        '<option value="PlatoLight Fuerte 3">Plato Fuerte 3</option>'+
    '</select>'+
    '<p>Postre: </p>'+
    '<select id="PostreLightID'+ i.toString() +'">'+
        '<option value=""></option>'+
        '<option value="PostreLight 1">Postre 1</option>'+
        '<option value="PostreLight 2">Postre 2</option>'+
        '<option value="PostreLight 3">Postre 3</option>'+
    '</select>'
    )}
```

```js
    var cantidadVegana = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= cantidadVegana; i++){
    $('#light').append(''+                         
'<p>Entrada: </p>'+
    '<select id="EntradaLightID'+ i.toString() +'">'+
        '<option value=""></option>'+
        '<option value="EntradaLight 1">Entrada 1</option>'+
        '<option value="EntradaLight 2">Entrada 2</option>'+
        '<option value="EntradaLight 3">Entrada 3</option>'+
    '</select>'+
    '<p>Plato fuerte: </p>'+
    '<select id="PlatoLightID'+ i.toString() +'">'+
        '<option value=""></option>'+
        '<option value="PlatoLight Fuerte 1">Plato Fuerte 1</option>'+
        '<option value="PlatoLight Fuerte 2">Plato Fuerte 2</option>'+
        '<option value="PlatoLight Fuerte 3">Plato Fuerte 3</option>'+
    '</select>'+
    '<p>Postre: </p>'+
    '<select id="PostreLightID'+ i.toString() +'">'+
        '<option value=""></option>'+
        '<option value="PostreLight 1">Postre 1</option>'+
        '<option value="PostreLight 2">Postre 2</option>'+
        '<option value="PostreLight 3">Postre 3</option>'+
    '</select>'
    )}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="light"></div>
```